# Error when i use Double in Codenameone

Tags: java, double, codenameone

Can't understand why I am getting this error when I declare `Double dblLng`.

```
valueOf(java.lang.String) in java.lang.Double cannot be applied to (double)
    Double dblLng = 0.0d;
Fatal Error: Unable to find method valueOf
```

Comment: show us the exact code you used to declare the variable.

Comment: IT there itself - Double dblLang = 0.0d;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of:

```
double dblLng = 0.0;
```

Or:

```
Double dblLng = new Double(0.0);
```

The reason you are getting this is due to autoboxing which seamlessly converts double to Double (if you don't understand the difference google Java autoboxing). This is a bug in the current version of Codename One where the valueOf methods required for autoboxing are missing from the whitelisted Java classes, I'll have a look at fixing it.

Comment: thanks. figured that out and just went with double rather than Double.